# how to check if all object keys has false values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

JS Object:

```
var saver = {
        title: false,
        preview: false,
        body: false,
        bottom: false,
        locale: false
};
```

The question is how to check if all values is **false**?

I can use $.each() jQuery function and some flag variable, but there may be a better solution?

Comment: you mean _without_ iterating through the properties?

Comment: Yep. I want to find more elegant solution.

Comment: A more elegant solution added below. You can do it *without iteration*, just using jQuery.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will do the trick...

```
var result = true;

for (var i in saver) {
    if (saver[i] === true) {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can iterate objects using a loop, either by index or key (as above).

If you're after tidy code, and not repeating that then simply put it in a function...

```
Object.prototype.allFalse = function() { 
    for (var i in this) {
        if (this[i] === true) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can call it whenever you need, like this...

```
alert(saver.allFalse());
```

Here's a working sample...

```js
Object.prototype.allFalse = function() { 
    for (var i in this) {
        if (this[i] === true) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var saver = {
        title: false,
        preview: false,
        body: false,
        bottom: false,
        locale: false
};

console.log("all are false - should alert 'true'");
console.log(saver.allFalse());

saver.body = true;

console.log("one is now true - should alert 'false'");
console.log(saver.allFalse());
```

Comment: Thnx. But this method is similar like my $.each() method. My question is how to avoid iterations?

Comment: You can't avoid iteration.  If there was a native way to do what you are asking, it would involve iteration in the background.  I think the best you can hope for is a small or tidy iteration.

Comment: You can't. And an iteration is far more efficient, otherwise if you changed the properties of the object you would have to change the code checking them.

Comment: Just changed it slightly to suit the specific "all properties false", rather than the "is there a true" approach that I took originally.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Looks like there no other methods than iteration. Oh well... =) But i definitely use your last remark about function.

Comment: I'm a big fan of prototyping, especially when it's so stupidly easy!  At least now your code will _look_ like there's a native call :)

Comment: How to handle that with nested keys ?

Comment: It's usually not recommended to modify global prototypes.

Answer (score 59):

Updated version.  Thanks @BOB for pointing out that you can use `values` directly:

```
Object.values(obj).every((v) => v === false)
```

Also, the question asked for comparison to `false` and most answers below return `true` if the object values are *falsy* (eg. `0, undefined, null, false`), not only if they are strictly false.

---

This is a very simple solution that requires JavaScript 1.8.5.

```
Object.keys(obj).every((k) => !obj[k])
```

Examples:

```
obj = {'a': true, 'b': true}
Object.keys(obj).every((k) => !obj[k]) // returns false

obj = {'a': false, 'b': true}
Object.keys(obj).every((k) => !obj[k]) // returns false

obj = {'a': false, 'b': false}
Object.keys(obj).every((k) => !obj[k]) // returns true
```

Alternatively you could write

```
Object.keys(obj).every((k) => obj[k] == false)
Object.keys(obj).every((k) => obj[k] === false)  // or this
Object.keys(obj).every((k) => obj[k])  // or this to return true if all values are true
```

See the [Mozilla Developer Network Object.keys()'s reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for further information.

Comment: `Object.values(obj).every((value) => value === false)` should also work.

Answer (score 16):

In a comment you ask if you can avoid iteration. You can if you use a javascript library supporting a functional approach, like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org), [Lodash](http://lodash.com) or [Sugar](http://sugarjs.com).

With Underscore and Lodash you can write something like this:

```
var result = _.every(_.values(saver), function(v) {return !v;});
```

With Sugar you can simply write:

```
var result = Object.all(saver,false);
```

Comment: You could also just do this in Lodash:

   `var result = _.every(_.valuesIn(saver), Boolean));`

Comment: Lodash: `const result = _.some(saver);`

Answer (score 13):

### Use array.some()

> It's more clean and understandable! And it can save us running time, because once the function condition exist once, it goes out of the loop and returns true.

```
Object.values(obj).some(val => val)
```

if you actually need strict equality to false write this:

```
Object.values(obj).some(val => val !== false)
```

`Object.values(obj)` make an array with the values of each key.

Answer (score 4):

Short and handy one-liner, fully supported by browsers:

```
Object.keys(saver).every(k => saver[k] === false);
```

or

```
Object.values(saver).every(v => v === false);
```

(careful tho, [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is not supported by **IE** yet.)

Answer (score 2):

This should work on all major browsers:

```
Object.keys(saver).every(key => saver[key] === false); // return true
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this,

```
 for (var i in saver) {
  if (saver[i]) {
    return false; // here if any value is true it wll return as false /
  }
 }
 return true; //here if all value is false it wll return as true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it *without external iteration* (i.e. in your code), try mapping the properties to an array with `$.map` then using `$.inArray` to see if any true values exist:

```
var allFalse = $.inArray(true, $.map(saver, function(obj){return obj})) < 0;
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/FLhZL/1/

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you could also do `const allFalse = !_.some(saver);`

Comment: They want to know if all are false (not true). So, if some are true, then not all are false.

Answer (score 1):

Lodash (3.10.1+) makes this even cleaner to express explicitly:

```
_.every({a: false, b: false, c: false}, _.negate(Boolean)); // True
```

But using `_.some` per [ngstschr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045337/885922) is more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

### ✏️  This one-liner checks if there's a falsy value inside any object of an array of objects:

```
const hasFalsyValue = (list) =>
 !list.every(obj => Object.values(obj).every(prop => prop))
```

I find this one useful to prevent null / falsy values from being passed further on:

```
const listA = [ { a:'', b:100 }, { a:'', b:200 } ]

const listB = [ { a:null, b:100 }, { a:'', b:200 } ]

// hasFalsyValue(listA) === false
// hasFalsyValue(listB) === true
```

There's just one detail we should be aware of:

⚠️ In Javascript **0** and **''** are Falsy values! ⚠️

So if hasFalsyValue() finds any zero value or any empty string value inside an object in the array, it will consider it a falsy value and thus return true!

...While this might be what you want, sometimes you might want to allow any particular Falsy value to be considered as Truthy.

✍  Say you want to allow zero values in your objects, you can do the following:

```
const hasFalsyValue_ZeroAllowed =
 (list) => !list.every(obj => Object.values(obj).every(prop =>  prop || prop === 0))
```

Now zero values won't be considered falsy anymore:

```
const listC = [ { a:0, b:100 }, { a:'', b:200 } ]
const listD = [ { a: null, b:100 }, { a:'', b:200 } ]

hasFalsyValue_ZeroAllowed(listC) // false
hasFalsyValue_ZeroAllowed(listD) // true
```

And you can keep on adding further conditions to the function for a tailored validation:

✍ To allow null values:

```
const hasFalsyValue_NullAllowed =
 (list) => !list.every(obj => Object.values(obj).every(prop =>  prop || prop === null))

const listE = [ { a: null, b:100 }, { a:'', b:200 } ]

hasFalsyValue_NullAllowed(listE) // false
```

✍ To allow empty string values:

```
const hasFalsyValue_EmptyStringAllowed =
 (list) => !list.every(obj => Object.values(obj).every(prop =>  prop || prop === ''))

const listF = [ { a: '', b:100 }, { a:'', b:200 } ]

hasFalsyValue_EmptyStringAllowed(listF)  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Lodash 4.0, [overEvery](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#overEvery) can be used

`overEvery(saver, false)` loops through every element & checks if its `false`

It returns `true` if every element is `false` otherwise returns `false`

Comment: I can't figure out the ES6 (Angular) syntax for that. it's returns a function I need it to return a boolean.

Comment: @tatsu post a new question with more details

Comment: This is incorrect, `overEvery` returns a function. Per docs: "**Creates a function** that checks if all of the predicates return truthy when invoked with the arguments it receives."