# Return if a falsy value is in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I want to happen is if any value is falsy, return just the error and never return the hooray. I'm using [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

```
var jawn = [
    {
        "cheese"  : true,
        "with"    : true,
        "without" : true
    },
    {
        "cheese"  : true,
        "with"    : true,
        "without" : true
    },
    {
        "cheese"  : true,
        "with"    : false,
        "without" : true
    },
    {
        "cheese"  : true,
        "with"    : true,
        "without" : true
    }      
];

_.forEach(jawn, function (item) {
    if(item.with === false) {
        console.log('error');
    } else {
        console.log('hooray');
    }
});
```

Comment: If you just want a falsy check, then `if (!item.with)` should work? Not sure what you're asking. Do you want to return the error if any of "cheese", "with", or "without" is falsy?

Comment: `jawn.some(o => !o.with)`

Comment: Check the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604734/how-to-check-if-all-object-keys-has-false-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your are using undescore, check [Collections.every/all](http://underscorejs.org/#every):

```
const msg = _(jawn).all(obj => obj.with) ? "hooray" : "error";
console.log(msg);
```

Comment: It will be great if you add some description

Answer (score 3):

```js
var jawn = [{
    "cheese": true,
    "with": true,
    "without": true
  }, {
    "cheese": true,
    "with": true,
    "without": true
  }, {
    "cheese": true,
    "with": false,
    "without": true
  },
  {
    "cheese": true,
    "with": true,
    "without": true
  }
];

const msg = jawn.some(item => !item.with) ? "error" : "hooray";
console.log(msg);
```